# Given $p(z)=|a_0|+\frac{|a_1|}{2}z+a_2z^2+\cdots+a_nz^n$ find $q(z)=|a_0|+|a_1|z+b_2z^2+\cdots+b_mz^m$ such that $\|q\| \leq \|p\|$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, geometry

Here $\|p\|=sup\{|p(z)|:z\in \mathbb{T}\} $ where $\mathbb{T}$ is the unit circle in the complex plane. $\|q\|$ is defined similarly. I have tried to use the following observations.

1. $sup|p(z)|=sup|p(-z)|$ over the unit circle.
2. $sup|p(z)|=sup|p(\bar{z})|$ over the unit circle.

I am unable to proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible in general. Say $p=1+z$. Then $||p||=2$, but if $q=1+2z+\dots$ then you can see, for example by Parseval, that $||q||\ge\sqrt 5$.

Comment: Why is \|q\| \geq \sqrt (5)

Comment: @Meow Because clearly $||q||\ge ||q||_2=\left(\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|q(e^{it}|^2\,dt\right)^{1/2}$ and Parseval shows $||q||_2\ge\sqrt 5$.

Comment: here there is some issue with your computation, i guess you are taking coefficient square while computing |q(e^(it))| but it should q(z)q(\bar(z)) so there will be some extra terms as well

Comment: @Meow Nonsense. Do you know what Parseval says? It has nothing to do with $q(z)q(\bar z)$. In fact $q(z)\overline{q(z)}=|q(z)|^2$.

Comment: @Meow Parseval: If $f(t)=\sum a_n e^{int}$ then $\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(t)|^2\,dt=\sum|a_n|^2$. Look it up...

Comment: @Meow Oh. I figured out what "extra terms" you're talking about. Yes, $|q(e^{it})|^2$ has some "extra terms".  The **integral** of those extra terms from $0$ to $2\pi$ is $0$. (General hint: When someone says that something you never heard of, say "Parseval", implies somethhing, probably you should check out the something you never heard of before saying the implication is wrong...)

Comment: I think the original problem has the wrong coefficients and $p$ needs to have a positive higher coefficient of $z$. Then it becomes a subordination exercise.